# Context.User is null in self-hosted SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, signalr, asp.net-identity, owin

I have an Azure Cloud Service project going, which consists of a Web Role and a Worker role. The Web Role is an MVC 5 app, the authentication setup on it is what is included with a standard MVC 5 project. On my worker role, I'm self-hosting a SignalR app. So far it's working fine, I can call the hub on my worker role from my web role, and vice versa. The problem, however, is that Context.User in the worker role SignalR hub is null, even though I'm  signed in on my web role.

I realize the problem is that authentication isn't properly wired up on my worker role, but I'm not sure how to go about that.  I'm sure the problem has something to do with the code in my Startup.cs on my worker role (which is very sparse), and possibly on my web role.

My web role Startup.Auth.cs, (gets called in Startup.cs):

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            CookieDomain = "127.0.0.1",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        ...
    }
}
```

The Startup.cs in my worker role only has logic for mapping SignalR, and enabling CORS.

I also realize I may be way out of my league, since I don't have any experience with OWIN, I just think this might not be too hard of a problem to solve.

Comment: The cookies generated by your Web Role will not be sent as part of the  cross-domain requests SignalR makes to your Worker role. `UseExternalSignInCookie` is meant for use with external login providers like Google or Facebook: http://brockallen.com/2014/01/09/a-primer-on-external-login-providers-social-logins-with-owinkatana-authentication-middleware/

Comment: I have the same problem now. Did you solve it? If yes, please share!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're setting cookie domain to 127.0.0.1. In any event, sounds like you're just looking to use the OWIN cookie authentication middleware? If so, here's an article that can help you understand it better:

http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/

SignalR will then just pickup whatever authentication you've established with the cookie middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I do need some sort of middleware on my worker role, but I'm afraid the article isn't of much help when it comes to that. I can log in fine on my web role, but when I call the hub on my worker role, Context.User is null. I'm guessing I need to authenticate user with the 'AspNet.ApplicationCookie' cookiue that is sent with the request from the web role to the worker role. How would I go about doing that